# All elements of An ArrayList change when a new one is added?

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, reference

First of all, apologies for not being able to supply any sourcecode. My project is pretty big and linking everything would be impractical, and I have not been able to scale down the problem which is exceedingly annoying. I will do my best to explain it here.

I am dynamically creating new instances of a class on each loop in my code. This instance is dynamically given a couple of properties while in the loop, 'name' for example. At the end of each loop, the newly generated instance is added to an ArrayList held in a another, 3rd, class.

The problem however is that when a new element is added, for whatever reason, all previous elements change to match exactly the latest. My guess is that the ArrayList is creating a reference to the dynamically created element so that whenever it changes, they all change, but I do not know how to fix this.

I would be grateful for any advice and apologies again for the quality of this explanation. I will post any specific piece of the code you may wish to see

As Requested - 
XmlHandler.java - http://pastebin.com/mGmWt1RD
ParsedDataSet.java = http://pastebin.com/k1xb3KBe
Content.java = http://pastebin.com/UxiL2f9q

Just to cut down on your comprehension time - The project is an epub reader. The XMLHandler is being called from a SAX parser in another class not shown. The XMLHandler is used 3 different times for 3 different XML sets so there is some clutter there.

The problem lies with the 'toc' ArrayList. The 'toc', or TableOfContents, holds the Contents instances to be referenced later (not shown). I am trying to pass data each new instance of 'Content' and then pass that into the static ArrayList

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've seen folks report this kind of problem many times, and it always comes down to this: you're actually *not* creating a new instance, but instead using the same one for each iteration of the loop. It's an easy mistake to make, especially if you're coming from a language with different copy semantics. There are a number of different ways you can make this mistake; if you edit your question to show the loop code, I'm sure I'll be able to explain what's happening.

OK, now that you've added the code: the problem is that in "Content", all the data member are marked "static". In Java, that means that there's one variable shared by all objects -- i.e., the variable has the same value for every object. SO in fact you *are* creating many Content objects to put in the ArrayList, but they all look identical! Remove those "static" attributes from Content's data members, and you'll be all set.

Comment: Yes, show us the looping and object creation code.

Comment: OK, the problem is that in "Content", all the data member are marked "static". In Java, that means that there's one variable shared by all objects -- i.e., the variable has the same value for every object. SO in fact you *are* creating many Content objects to put in the ArrayList, but they all look identical! Remove those "static" attributes from COntent's data members, and you'll be all set!

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner, had to sleep. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but now all the 'Content' properties are turning blank and I'm not sure why

Comment: Looking at `XmlHandler`, I think the logic starting at line 33 is suspect. I think whenever you hit a "navPoint" element, *or any element contained inside a navPoint*, you're going to create a new `Content`. This will actually result in a lot of `Content` objects getting created, having one parameter set, and then thrown away. The constructor call at line 38 should occur if and only if `qName` equals "navPoint"; it should definitely *not* occur if `inNavPoint` is already true, because that will throw the previous "live" `Content` object away.

Comment: I can't thank you enough :) I got rid of my faulty logic and replaced it with your correct simpler system, of course it works perfectly now! This is the new XmlHandler file if your interested - http://pastebin.com/WuQb4nWr. I still have to use a inNavPoint Check, note sure why, but it works!

Comment: it worked for me .. :)

Answer (score 17):

`ArrayList` just stores reference of elements. Ensure that your code looks like:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
loop(...) {
    MyObject newOne = new MyObject();
    newOne.setXXX(xxx);
    list.add(newOne);
}
```

Wrong code:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
MyObject sameOne = new MyObject();
loop(...) {
    sameOne.setXXX(xxx);
    list.add(sameOne);
}
```

Comment: Working good...Thanks a lot