# Android ListView Duplicates entries

Tags: android-intent, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, arrays, android-adapterview

If i type "Hello" in my edittext in activity 1 it will add "Hello" to the listview in activity 2 as the first entry ( which has no error ). Also, if I type "Apple" as my second entry I will change the first entry of "Hello" to "Apple" and add the new 2nd entry "Apple"... causing both entries to become "Apple" and "Apple"... any thoughts?

Act2
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_argue_list);

```
    ListView txtlist = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);


    Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
     Lrg = bun.getString("Jenny");
     Med = bun.getString("Forest");
     Med2 = bun.getString("Gump");

        KoreyzAdapter add = new KoreyzAdapter();
        txtlist.setAdapter(add);
        list.add(0, Lrg);
        add.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setListAdapter(add);
}
class KoreyzAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

      public KoreyzAdapter() {
          super(ArgueListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    }
      class ViewHolder{
          TextView who;
          TextView sex;
          TextView cat;
          ImageView pic;

          ViewHolder(View v){
              who = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.inputLrgtxt);
              sex = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.whoMedtxt);
              cat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.stupidMedtxt);
              pic = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.sexpic);
          }

      }
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View row = convertView;
                    ViewHolder holder = null;
                    if(row == null){

                         LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                        holder = new ViewHolder(row);
                        row.setTag(holder);

                    }else{
                        holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
                    }

                        holder.who.setText(Lrg);
                        holder.sex.setText(Med);
                        holder.cat.setText(Med2);

                        holder.pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.maleandfemale);

                        return row;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the adapter data. Before loading the listView from adapter make the list clear at **onCreate()** of your activity. It is just appending the old data. That's why it is showing two times. 
I hope this will work.

**Use this one onCreate():**

```
list.clear()
```

Comment: We'll i want the listview to keep entries like a notepad app list.clear seems to erase the entry. I may have placed it in the wrong place currently its right after setContentView(R.layout.activity_argue_list);

Comment: It depends on how you are loading the data. With out seeing your code i can't tell you much. This works for me. you can only know where to place the thing. It will definitely works..

Comment: ya i understood...you are sending each row at time...it will add a single row to the list

Comment: but why its duplicating the previous entry is where Im lost at. Doesnt make any sense.

Comment: duplicating the new entry i mean

Comment: Dude you are using this one..
 'list.add(0, Lrg);' may be this is the reason...always It is taking the 0th one..Just try list.add(lrg);

Comment: I thought that may have been it as well. I've made a few changes to that line any ideas on what to change it to?

Comment: sorry had to make a few other changes to the code. It populates but does the same thing after removing the 0

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608828/all-elements-of-an-arraylist-change-when-a-new-one-is-added) link. It might help you as well.

Even I was facing the same problem it took me 2 days to get rid of that issue.

I hope this helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

With ArrayAdapters always pass the layout of the list row items in the constructor.

Example : `TodosAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Todo> todos);`

int layoutResourceId is android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1